# Hibernate/Spring: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions in unit test

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am seeing the above error in my unit tests, and am at a loss how to correct it.

My unit test class extends AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests and performs the following:

```
// Retrieve a RuleGroup
RuleGroup ruleGroupToUpdate = ruleGroupDao.findRuleGroup(a, b, c, d);
// Update an encapsulated Attribute
// Save the RuleGroup
ruleGroupDao.updateRuleGroup(ruleGroupToUpdate);
```

The following is a snippet of my RuleGroup mapping file. As you can see, a RuleGroup has encapsulated Rule and Attribute collections, both of which are lazy loaded by default:

```
<class name="a.b.c.d.RuleGroup" table="RULE_GROUP">
    <id name="ruleGroupID" column="RULE_GRP_ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <set name="rules" lazy="true" cascade="save-update" table=RULES">
        <key column="RULE_GRP_ID" not-null="false"/>
        <many-to-many unique="true" column="RULE_ID" class="a.b.c.d.Rule"/>
    </set>
    <set name="attributes" lazy="true" cascade="save-update" table="ATTRIBUTES">
        <key property-ref="xrefID" column="XREF_ID" not-null="true"/>
        <many-to-many unique="true" column="CONFIG_ATTR_ID" class="a.b.c.d.Attribute"/>             
    </set>
</class>
```

My DAO class extends HibernateDaoSupport:

The findRuleGroup method uses getSession().createCriteria() to perform the query. The rules and attributes are retrieved using a "join" fetch

The updateRuleGroup method uses getHibernateTemplate().update() to perform the update

From debugging my test, a new Session is created in the findRuleGroup method, and then again in the updateRuleGroup method. Therefore, when the update is performed Hibernate sees that my Attribute collection is already associated with the findRuleGroup session and throws the exception.

How do I resolve this? Presumably, the update should not open a new session. If I specify that HibernateTemplate should not create a new session, then I get a different exception saying there is no session associated with the thread. I am at a loss here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have a transaction at all. getHibernateTemplate() can open a new session. see the src code here: [bit.ly/HsgDrR](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.java). A common practice is to use spring's @Transactional annotation to wrap methods in your dao in a transaction. If you don't do this, calling anything other than getSession() can cause new sessions to be opened outside your transaction and leak.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I don't wish to specify @Transactional at DAO level what other options do I have? If I use Hibernate without HibernteTemplate would this avoid a new session being created?

Comment: Just to specify my fix. I removed AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests and used the Spring 3 unit testing support instead whereby I specified the @Transactional annotation on each of my unit tests instead. So this provided transactional support in my unit tests and the error no longer occurred. Thanks!